# How to write to next line in a csv file in java using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file, csv, fileoutputstream

I have a result obtained in the variable average_time which I later converted to bytes in order to get it written in a csv file. The result is obtained three times as I have used a loop. I want the results to be printed one by one below in the same column. But the problem is that all the values are being written in the same cell. How can I solve this problem?

```
    try{    
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("testout.csv");
        String str=Integer.toString(average_time);
        byte b[]=str.getBytes();
        out.write(b);
        }
        out.close();
         //System.out.println("success...");    
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}    
  }
```

I expect it to be 
15 (newline)
31 (newline)
48 (newline)

But it shows
153148

Comment: You need to write out out.write("\n") after each number is printed.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: Tip: Much easier to use a library such as [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/csv/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "\n" to **str** before write it to file:

```
String str=Integer.toString(average_time) + "\n";
```

Comment: "*Just add "/n" to str before write it to file:*" -  `\n`

Comment: @Nexevis no! Please don't. [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) returns an OS-dependent line-separator. With this, you set yourself up for encoding-trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `out.write("\n".getBytes());` after `out.write(b);`  it should give you the output you are looking for